# Rails session still alive after db:drop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I'm curious  why `session` left alive after `rake db:drop`?

I have

```
  def current_order
    if !session[:order_id].nil?
     @current_order =  Order.find(session[:order_id])
    else
      Order.new
    end
  end
  helper_method :current_order
```

and after rake db:drop it gives me exception

```
Couldn't find Order with 'id' = my session number
>> session[:order_id]
=> 11
```

that means session still there. But Why?

Comment: Are you storing sessions in the database? By default  I think they're stored using cookies

Comment: Correct @tpbowden. CookieStore has been the default since Rails 2. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage

Comment: @tpbowden no i do not save session in db,than how i can delete session with rake db:reset?

Comment: Try changing your secret key base, I think that will invalidate them all

Comment: Or check out the active record session store gem

Comment: Try changing your secret key base-- can i  do it inside seed.rb? and than restrart app?

Comment: No it is changed using config/secrets.yml

Answer (score 1):

Rails by default uses `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore` to store the session. Thus cleaning out the database does not remove any session data as it is held by the client.

Instead you would remove the cookies in the browser (in development) or change the secret key base to invalidate existing cookies.

See:

- [Ruby on Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage)

Comment: How can i do it on server side? except changes in `config/secrets.yml`

Comment: There is no other way AFAIK except by changing the session storage mechanism to something else than `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore`.  For production you would change `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` instead of the YAML file.